# Is there any way to print and download a div as an image in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'd like to create two buttons that will perform action like download and print a div.

Onclick download button my div should convert into image and start downloading, onclick print button my div should print.

I am gonna add onclick functions on my buttons, so please make two separate functions.
ex- function download(); function print();

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCfIf.png)

HTML

```html
<div class="canvas" id="canvas">stackoverflow</div>

<button onclick="print()">Print</button>
<button onclick="download()">Download</button>
```

Thank you in advance!

I a newby in javascript, currently creating projects to learn javascript. I tried many ways from stackoverflow but don't know how to implement it in my code.

Comment: Maybe https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-take-screenshot-of-a-div-using-javascript/ can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [html2canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2canvas) in Vue2.0, here is the example code in App.vue.
As for printing, this code cannot print the <div>stackoverflow</div> directly. Otherwise, this code can generate an image in the body if you click the "download" button first, then you can click the "print" button to print the generated image.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="canvas">stackoverflow</div>

    <button @click="print">Print</button>
    <button @click="download">Download</button>

    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';

export default {
  name: "App",
  methods: {
    download() {
      html2canvas(document.querySelector(".canvas")).then(canvas => {
        const imgUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'); // convert image to base 64 as type of jpeg
        const image = document.createElement('img') // create an element 'img' which is named as image
        image.src = imgUrl // equeal to <image src="imgUrl"></image>
        document.querySelector('.content').appendChild(image)
        const a = document.createElement('a')
        a.href = imgUrl // set <a href=""></a> for downloading
        a.download = 'stackoverflow'
        a.click()
      })
    },
    print() {
      window.print()
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
.canvas {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}
</style>
```